# How to insert consecutive numbers in columns JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to put consecutive numbers in rows and columns.
First part looks easy. Now I have a problem with second part, with putting consecutive values in columns. 
I've already done this next way:

```
let tableDisplay = document.querySelector('#table');

function createTable() {
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    let tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    table.border = '1';

    for (let r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        tableBody.appendChild(row);

        for (let c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            let cell = document.createElement('td');
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    tableDisplay.appendChild(table);
}

createTable();

let tr = document.querySelector('tbody').querySelectorAll('tr');
let td = document.querySelectorAll('td');
let counter = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    counter++;
    td[i].innerHTML = counter;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what is the issue with what you have?

Comment: So u want to create a new table with consecutive numbers in a column?

Comment: Yes, I want a new table with consecutive numbers in a column

Answer (score 0):

The latest for loop should iterate over tr.childNodes.length, and then you could set the value of the counter to each column.

tr >> rows

td >> cols